# .NetCore 2.x on using {*catchAll} routing URL.Action always returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I am using this route to map all routes which were not found:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "NotFound",
    template: "{*url}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "NotFound" }
);
```

The problem I encountered is that `@Url.Action()` always returns `null` on this route.

Could someone explain why is this happening and what could be alternatives to this?

Comment: If you want to get /Home/NotFound/ url or any other url you can always use <a href="/Home/NotFound">Url</a> instead or Url.Action. Given it's not the nicest but i will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around, I found a "cheat" way to do it and it kinda works. If I get **NotFound** page then I redirect back to the same page if `Url.Action() == null`

```
if(this._urlService.Action() == null) //same urlHelper action, only has default Home page values passed into method
{
    var query = string.Empty;
    if(Request.QueryString.HasValue)
    {
        query = Request.QueryString.Value;
    }
    var path = "/Home/NotFound" + query;
    path = string.Concat("/", this._userIdentity.CurrentLanguage.ToString().ToLower(), path);
    return base.Redirect(path);
 }
```

It could be because I use `/{culture}/{Controller}/{Action}` as my main route. Creating other test project, where my main route is default `/{Controller}/{Action}` has no problem at all finding the `Url.Action()` on **NotFound** page

Answer (score 2):

you have to add the below code before the app.UseMvc(...[Routing] ...), make sure you use it in the right order because the order really matters, the pipeline in asp.net core is in reverse order meaning that if you add A before B then B will be called before A, you can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#order

```cs
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
```

and in the controllers consider an ErrorController which contains different error codes here we just consider 404 and 500 errors in ErrorController, we must have the corresponding views for each error code (404, 500, Unknown)

```cs
 public class ErrorController : ControllerBase
    {
        [Route("error/{code:int}")]
        public ActionResult Error(int code)
        {
            switch (code)
            {
                case 404: return View("404");
                case 500: return View("500");
                default: return View("Unknown");
            }
        }
    }
```

for more concise description please check Microsoft documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: I've seen this approach but I use cultures in my URL and all my urls starts with /{culture}/{Controller}/{Action} to set each pages language. As I have to register one url in app configuration, this method is not what I'm looking for. But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you call `@Url.Action()` either with *route parameters* (e.g. `controller = "Home", action = "NotFound"`) or with *route name* - that makes no difference - to generate a URL to your *not found* page. Well, you said the URL can be any thing which effects in **in-bound routing** and it's just fine. But, when you are trying to generate URLs from a route (**out-bound routing**), the route hasn't any template to generate a URL. In route's perspective, it can be any URL. So, `null` is any URL too. So, the `null` will be returned.